# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable during normalization

Tags: min

I'm performing feature scaling(normalization) on my dataset, using below code:

## Nomalisation

```
for i in cnames:

print(i)

churn_train[i] = (churn_train[i] - min(churn_train[i]))/(max(churn_train[i]) - min(churn_train[i]))
```

But, i am getting the error:

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>
> in ()
>
> ```
>   2 for i in cnames:
>   3     print(i)
> ```
>
> ----> 4     churn_train[i] = (churn_train[i] - min(churn_train[i]))/(max(churn_train[i]) - min(churn_train[i]))
>
> TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please could you format your code to make it easier to read? You can always go back to modify your questions (and answers). The editor has buttons to perform simple markup like code, quote and link.

Answer (score 0):

try below code in python

```
for i in cnames:

     print(i)

     churn_train[i] = (churn_train[i] - churn_train[i].min())/(churn_train[i].max()) - min(churn_train[i]))
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/24116529).